# How to make Json.Net skip serialization of empty collections

Tags: c#, asp.net, serialization, json.net

I have an object that contains several properties that are a List of strings `List<String>` or a dictionary of strings `Dictionary<string,string>`.   I want to serialize the object to json using Json.net and I want to have the least amount of text generated.

I am using the DefaultValueHandling and NullValueHandling to set default values to strings and integers.  But how can I define the DefaultValueHandling to ignore the property in the serialized output if it is initialized to an empty `List<String>` or `Dictionary<string,string>`?

Some sample output is:

```
{
 "Value1": "my value",
 "Value2": 3,
 "List1": [],
 "List2": []
}
```

I want to get a result that ignores the two lists in the above example, because they are set to the default value of an empty list.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: I don't think that is possible. I'm sure it wouldn't be too difficult to ignore `null` values but that would require you to make changes elsewhere so that those references are null rather than pointing to an empty list.

Comment: I am sure this can be done with a custom converter (by implementing the abstract class JsonConverter), But I am too lazy for now to provide a code.

Comment: I found this article that contains a reference to the IContractResolver.   http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2009/10/23/efficient-json-with-json-net-reducing-serialized-json-size.aspx   That seems to be a good lead to find a way to implement this.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I have implemented this feature in the [custom contract resolver](https://github.com/Athari/Alba.Framework/blob/master/Alba.Framework.Serialization.Json/Common/JsonLinkedContractResolver.cs) of my personal framework (link to the [specific commit](https://github.com/Athari/Alba.Framework/blob/d6492bc7d0530ece361d5ea82f16f563dd98e16d/Alba.Framework.Serialization.Json/Common/JsonLinkedContractResolver.cs) in case the file will be moved later). It uses some helper methods and includes some unrelated code for custom references syntax. Without them, the code will be:

```
public class SkipEmptyContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    public SkipEmptyContractResolver (bool shareCache = false) : base(shareCache) { }

    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty (MemberInfo member,
            MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        JsonProperty property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
        bool isDefaultValueIgnored =
            ((property.DefaultValueHandling ?? DefaultValueHandling.Ignore)
                & DefaultValueHandling.Ignore) != 0;
        if (isDefaultValueIgnored
                && !typeof(string).IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType)
                && typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType)) {
            Predicate<object> newShouldSerialize = obj => {
                var collection = property.ValueProvider.GetValue(obj) as ICollection;
                return collection == null || collection.Count != 0;
            };
            Predicate<object> oldShouldSerialize = property.ShouldSerialize;
            property.ShouldSerialize = oldShouldSerialize != null
                ? o => oldShouldSerialize(o) && newShouldSerialize(o)
                : newShouldSerialize;
        }
        return property;
    }
}
```

This contract resolver will skip serialization of all empty collections (all types implementing `ICollection` and having `Length == 0`), unless `DefaultValueHandling.Include` is specified for the property or the field.

Comment: I think you can remove the need for `memberProp` and `memberField` by doing `object value = property.ValueProvider.GetValue(obj);`.

Comment: I do already use a other contract resolver (CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver) can I use both parallel?

Comment: @Gerwald You'll need to join their code. JSON.NET doesn't support combining contract resolvers.

Comment: @Discord: ok, thanks a lot. But thats too bad for good reusability. With join, I guess, you mean inheriting?

Comment: @Gerwald Either inheriting or copy-pasting (if inheriting doesn't work). If you need you can create a contract resolver which supports composition, I think. Shouldn't require much code. But you'll definitely have to copy-paste CamelCase resolver's code then.

Comment: That's not working as expected, `property.DefaultValueHandling` is always null even if I set it explicitly in the configuration

Answer (score 10):

Another very simple solution is to implement a `ShouldSerialize*` method in the type being serialized as outline [here](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConditionalProperties.htm).

This might be the preferred way if you're in control of the type being serialized and if it is not a general behavior you want to introduce.